# Accessing to 2D array with a range in Swift

Tags: swift

When I construct 2D array as follows, and apply `flatMap` with a range on it, I get the following result:

```
var a = [["5", "3", ".", ".", "7", "."],["6",".",".","1","9","5"]]
print(a.flatMap{$0[1..<5]})
```

output:

> `["3", ".", ".", "7", ".", ".", "1", "9"]`

But if I want to just display the range as follows, I am getting the following error.

```
print(a[1..<5])
```

> Terminated by signal 4

Comment: And what’s the question?

Comment: I wonder why I am getting crash?

Comment: That's because it doesn't make sense.  You only have two arrays of strings included in a.

Comment: It would make more sense if you wrote something like a[0][1..<5].

Comment: yes, you get the error. you have 2 items in your root-array, therefore you cannot `print(a[1..<5])` because there is not enough element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is exactly what one would expect. `a` has just two elements, indexed as 0 and 1. Applying a larger index by saying `a[1..<5]` (asking also for elements 2, 3, and 4) puts you out of range.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the elements in the range as columns of the 2D Array, then you could get them this way:

```
let a = [["5", "3", ".", ".", "7", "."],
         ["6", ".", ".", "1", "9", "5"]]

func getColumns<T>(in range: Range<Int>, from array2d: [[T]]) -> [T] {
    return array2d.flatMap { $0[range] }
}

getColumns(in: 1..<5, from: a)  //["3", ".", ".", "7", ".", ".", "1", "9"]
```

Bear in mind that this could still throw an *Index out of range* error just like with any other array.

Comment: What happened to your question at CR?

Comment: I take it from your question that I could bring it back. And it's up again. Thank you for caring!

Comment: This code doesn’t do what this question asked. The OP wants `["3", ".", ".", "7", ".", ".", "1", "9"]` from `1..<5`. It feels like you’ve answered a different question.

Comment: @Rob there you go, my answer's gone on a diet